# How can I select entities from Apache Usergrid with single quote

Tags: database, apache, escaping, usergrid, single-quotes

I'm trying to figure out how to escape a single quote for a query of a Usergrid collection.  I can't find anything about it in the documentation or online.  For example I have a Book collection and I want to select those with the title "Charolette's Web"

```
/books/?ql=select*where title = 'Charlotte\'s Web'
```

This query does not give back any results from the database query.  I also tried '' as the escape character (like sql) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to escape quotes in a ql request at the current time.

You could work around this by using a `contains` clause:

```
?ql=select * where title contains 'Charlotte'
```

I've opened an issue for it to be looked at [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/USERGRID-1041).

Comment: This is based on a user input though.  If they enter "Charlotte's Web" I'm having trouble getting the correct entry to be retrieved

Comment: Right - contains will still return the entity; you'll just have to do a filter check on it afterward. Of course this also assumes you know the name you're querying for.